# Why is Axios throwing 500 errors in catch?

Tags: reactjs, express, request, graphql, axios

I have a Graphql Express backend.
I've tested the request using localhost:3001/graphql.

My frontend Axios request looks like this:

```
export const login = (formData, setUser, setLoading) => {
  setLoading(true)
  axios.post('', {
    variables: {
      email: formData.email,
      username: formData.username,
      password: formData.password,
    },
    query: `
      query Login(${formData.email ? `$email: String!` : `$username: String!`}, $password: String!) {
        login(${formData.email ? `email: $email` : `username: $username`}, password: $password) {
          _id
          token
          token_expiry
          logged_in_at
          geolocation
          name
          username
          email
          bio
          profile_img
          dark_mode
        }
      }
    `
  }).then(res => {
    if (res.data.errors) {
      process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development' && console.log(res.data.errors[0].message)
    } else {
      const userData = {...res.data.data.login, geolocation: JSON.parse(res.data.data.login.geolocation)}
      setUser(logInSuccess(userData))
    }
    setLoading(false)
  }).catch(err => {
    process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development' && console.log(err)
    setLoading(false)
  })
}
```

My problem is this:

- When I test this request using localhost:3001/graphql with a correct password I get a 200 response with my data.
- When I test this request using localhost:3001/graphql with an incorrect password I get the thrown error I want which would return in res.data.errors. This error is thrown when bcrypt.compareSync returns false.
- When I make this request in the frontend with a correct password I get a 200 response with my response data.

--- When I make this request in the frontend with an incorrect password I get a 500 error in .catch! What am I missing here?

Things I've tried:

I've tried removing the ternary from the request making it work for a simple email - password combination.

This is the 500 Error:

```
Error: Request failed with status code 500
    at createError (createError.js:17)
    at settle (settle.js:19)
    at XMLHttpRequest.handleLoad (xhr.js:60)
    at XMLHttpRequest.onreadystatechange (<anonymous>:1:807)
```

Comment: Odd. When you get the 500 status, what's the actual response body from the server? You can view this in your browser's dev tools.

Comment: I've updated the question to include the 500 Error.

Comment: In catch block, can you `console.log(err.response.data)` to see the actual problem?

Comment: Ah! My thrown error is under err.response.data.errors[0]! But what is it doing there and not in .then like the rest of my backend errors?